# django and urls

Tags: django, url

I have a problem.

I Have urls like that :

```
/articles/rating/month/
/articles/viewing/day/
...
```

So for these urls, I have  a function **view_articles**() with parameters : **sorting**,**order**.

Everything works fine.

But,now I think it would be great if, when I visit one of these urls, I go in a function **articles**() which returns all the articles, which are passed in argument to the function **sorting**() which returns the result which is passed to the function **order**() which return an **HttpResponse**().

But well  don't know :
 - if it's a good idea,
 - how to do it in the urls.py 
 - if there is already an app to do that.

That's all,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like the [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter) project might be suitable.